Qtreeview and QFilesystemModel can not show a broken link file
I encounter a strange problem and can not figure out a solution:
I use just QTreeview and QFileSystemModel to display a directory on windows. there are several shortcut files inside (.lnk). somehow only shortcut files, which are still active, shown in the Treeview. the broken link file (for example, no connection to USF Disk/Network) will be just ignored.
does anyway have an idea how to fix it?
I have got some codes from Copilot, but it doesnt work either:
class CustomFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        index = self.index(row, 0, parent)
        if not index.isValid():
            return False

        file_info = QFileInfo(self.filePath(index))
        # Check if the file is a shortcut link and if it's broken
        if file_info.isSymLink() and not file_info.exists():
            return True  # Show broken links

        return super().filterAcceptsRow(row, parent)

